# Android ViewPager's onPageScrollStateChanged never gets called

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have extended the ViewPager class and implemented onPageChangeListener.
I use this ViewPager in conjunction with a CirclePageIndicator inside a SherlockFragment. The ViewPager contains ImageViews and TextViews, nothing fancy.

I need to do something below the ViewPager every time the Page is being changed. So, I figured I need to use the onPageScrollStateChanged and verify when the state is  IDLE, or something.

The problem is that from the 3 implemented methods (onPageScrollStateChanged, onPageSelected and onPageScrolled), only onPageScrolled gets called (I checked with a log message in each method). Why is that ? Code below.

```
public class UninterceptableViewPager extends ViewPager implements OnPageChangeListener{

private ArrayList<TwoRowListViewAdapter> mAdaptersList = null;
private ListView mListView = null;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;


public UninterceptableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}


public void setAdaptersList(ArrayList<TwoRowListViewAdapter> adaptersList)
{
    mAdaptersList = adaptersList;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
{
    super.onPageScrolled(position++, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    if (positionOffset == 0) // FIXME
        loadHistoryPage(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------   Helper Methods
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public void setListView(ListView listview)
{
    mListView = listview;
}

public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    mProgressBar = progressBar;
}

private void loadHistoryPage(int position)
{
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mListView.setAdapter(null);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdaptersList.get(position-1));
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When you use PageIndicator in conjunction with the Viewpager then the onPageChangeListener of the ViewPager is not called. I don't know the reason for this but this happened when I was using both. May be cause the page indicator consumes the page change event. Instead you should set a page change listener to the PageIndicator and it will be called when the page changes. Here is how you can do this:

```
indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected (int page)
        {
            //page changed
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled (int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int arg0)
        {
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help. Feel free to discuss.

Comment: Yes, I think your assumption is correct. Well, I need to verify it, but it does make sense. Thank you very much for this perfect answer ! I'll test the solution tomorrow and report my findings.

Comment: author wrote here http://viewpagerindicator.com/#usage

"If you use an OnPageChangeListener with your view pager you should set it in the indicator rather than on the pager directly." e.g.

titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. The reason is the indicator assigns itself as the onPageChangeListener for the ViewPager. Thankfully, the indicator then exposes the same interface so others can connect their listener. So the events flow from ViewPager -> Indicator -> Your listener.

Answer (score 0):

`setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated.
use `addOnPageChangeListener`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```